# Angular can not read property of undefined

Tags: angular

I have the following in my component:

```
public allStats:any;
getAllTurbinesStat(id:string) {

  this.service.getAllTurbinesStat(id).subscribe(s => {
   this.allStats=s;
  });
 }
```

in my html:

```
 <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">      
           {{ allStats[0].all }}
           </div>
```

it actually works and shows the data but in my console, i get this error? why is that? and if it does not recognize why does it show the value on my browser?

the data i get from back end is:

```
0: {all: 2, starT_UP: 3, service: 5, run: 183, linK_DOWN: 75, …}
```

Comment: Use safe navigation operator: `{{ (allStats || [])[0]?.all }}`. The variable `allStats` isn't defined by the time the template is rendered. The safe navigation operator will check if the variable is defined before accessing it's properties.

Comment: @MichaelDthanks a million,its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is when component is rendered value is undefined

```html
 <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center" *ngIf="allStats && allStats.length">      
           {{ allStats[0].all }}
           </div>
```

Comment: thanks reza jan,can you send me a PM in chat?I have a question

Comment: me either! I will send you an email

Answer (score 1):

Your api call will not be done before the first render, so `allStats` will stille be undefined.

There is a typical pattern used in SPAs, where there are multiple cases for async data in the template:

- loading
- loaded

This can e.g. look like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="allStats; else loading">
  {{ allStats[0].all }}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading> ...loading </ng-template>
```